# Do moving charges really produce magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism

If moving charges produce magnetic fields and since every object has electrons, when we move the object the electrons in it move as well. So why isn't a magnetic field produced when we move an object?

Comment: Electrons and protons both will move thus cancelling  each other's field

Comment: But they are at different places so produce different magnetic fields. though magnitude is same direction is not same so there should be some net magnetic field.

Comment: Electrons moving around orbits in atoms produce magnetic effects in substances, like paramagnetism, diamagnetism, ferromagnetism and the like. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: No, not talking about that.

Comment: @RNR , Although the proton and electron are in different places, the distance between them is too small to fit any other object(so that it can measure a net field, if thats what you meant by "they are at different places") . If an electron produces magnetic field in clockwise,  a proton will produce the same magnetic field anticlockwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better picture would be the one in which a rod is placed in some car, then there would be two frames. The first one is a car frame and the other is a lab frame. In the lab frame, the rod is moving while in the car frame the rod is at rest.

Now I'll state the result without getting into proofs that would make the answer long but see Electricity and magnetism by Purcell.

$$\mathbf{E}'_\parallel=\mathbf{E}_\parallel \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \mathbf{E}'_\perp=\gamma (\mathbf{E}_\perp+\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{B}_\perp)$$
$$\mathbf{B}'_\parallel=\mathbf{B}_\parallel \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \mathbf{B}'_\perp=\gamma (\mathbf{B}_\perp-(\mathbf{v}/c^2)\times \mathbf{E}_\perp)$$
where $\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity of $F'$ frame with respect to $F$.

---

> Why isn't a magnetic field produced when we move any object.

If you are in an unprimed coordinate that is moving with respect to the rod, you will measure the magnetic field. The crazy fact is that the field are not invariant when you go from one coordinate to different coordinate.

Comment: So in short,  Magnetic fields can be produced (in one frame) by only those bodies which can also produce an Electric fields (in some other frame) so as to keep the effects of the field invariant.

Comment: Not only, but there are also many ways to produce a magnetic field. It's not necessary that you can always find a frame where one of the fields gets vanish. Their result of an experiment would remain the same. It's $\mathbf{E}\cdot \mathbf{B}$ and $|\mathbf{B}|^2c^2-|\mathbf{E}|^2$ are also invariant under the transformation.